# Как  сделать push на удаленный сервер без Git?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, hosting

*Имеем:*

- shared-хостинг (linux-based), доступ
     к нему по ssh, но там нет  git;
- среда разработки: ubuntu 14.04, настроенный
     LAMP, локальный git-репозитарий.

*Вопрос: как при помощи этих инструментов организовать рабочий процесс?*

*Желаемое:*  при каждом коммите в ветку production отправлять изменения на сервер.

*Сейчас:* вручную(

Comment: http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/

http://www.lyraphase.com/wp/projects/how-to-build-git-for-a-host-with-no-compiler/

Вот есть несколько ссылок по теме. Просто собирается git из исходников и экспортируется в локальную PATH переменную.

Comment: сейчас посмотрим (изменю комментарий позже)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А это вообще правильно на сервере держать гит с проектом? У меня проект локально хранится и кодится на моей станции, а уже готовый продук деплоится на сервак. Средствами **SCP**  и т.п.

Comment: @Bimawa, во-первых, надежнее, если код дублируется в удаленном репозитории, во-вторых, разработчик может быть не один. Правда, в обоих случаях удобнее использовать гитхаб, битбакет или аналоги.

Comment: @Bimawa, спасибо за эти три буквы... SCP, оформите ответом - это то что надо нам), просто не знал, как написать. Да, у нас битбакет -  два разработчика.

Comment: @shilgen, я думал "Сейчас: вручную(" это и имелось ввиду scp :)

Comment: @iksuy, ну это естественно, ну, как меня уже правильно понял @KoVadim, он снял с языка. rsync для деплоя плохой инструмент, так как обычно перед деплоем проходит итерация и предеплойский проект крутится и тестируется. А rsync будет все время синкать его, не по нужде. Хотя это тоже все настраивается и особо сути не менят даже ftp подойдет )

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что держать на рабочем сервере git репозиторий немного плохо. Уже было несколько прецедентов с [яндексом](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/) и другими.

Правильно - настроить гитхаб или гитлаб, куда могут пушить все разработчики, и держать ветку release, для которой настроить хук. При пуше в эту ветку изменения выливаются на продакшн. У них даже есть готовые системы - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/

Но если от себя - то можно вместо scp использовать rsync. Это тот же протокол, просто он умеет синхронизировать по умному.